# Install Ubuntu 12.04 from Pen drive, now will not boot

Tags: 64-bit, boot-failure, ssd, usb-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed ubuntu 12.04 desktop amd64 to the following:

AMD A8 3870K (CPU + GPU)

ASUS F1Aff-M LX plus motherboard

G skill 16gb ram (1333)

OCZ agt3-25sat3-120g 120gb SSD (OS HDD)

WD RED NAS 1TB HDD (Storage)
WD RED NAS 2TB HDD (Storage)
WD RED NAS 2TB HDD (Storage)

450 watt power supply

This is a clean install, no previous OS

Ubuntu booted from the flash dive without a problem, and installed to my SSD, i am using this as the OS HDD and told it to install there, no partition.

Install went fine, put my user name, comp name etc. in, and then when it asked to restart, it restarted and then nothing came on the screen.  my monitor told me no signal, and that was all.

I was thinking maybe a power problem, so i disconnected all of 2 of HDD (left the 1tb and the OS), and still nothing is booting.  I just to this purple screen that is a box to the left of center, and nothing not even a command prompt.

Is there something I did wrong? How do i reinstall, as it is not letting me do that, or is my power supply not good enough, or is the A8 chipset not compatible with ubuntu?

Comment: What happens if you plug in the Pen Drive, leave it plugged in,  and power the system on?

Comment: nothing, BUT i found my own solution:

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

I have found my own answer, it is located in this link about resetting ubuntu's graphics driver to generic:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Excellent, David. Since that's the solution I'll go ahead and suggest that this be closed as a duplicate of the link. Thanks for contributing.